# Floor in SceneKit is vertically oriented in runtime

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Trying to make shadows in scene kit and got succeed in scene editor but when I run the app floor which is used for shadow oriented vertically not horizontally and I don't understand why this so.

Objects I use in editor has good shadows and oriented same way as in runtime but floor is not.

Here is how my cube looks like in editor[image]

When I add floor to the scene editor it is vertical towards to other items on the scene and I use Euler x -90 to make it correct.

When I run the app all objects looks the same as in scene editor but floor is positioned vertically.

If I not apply Euler x -90 to the floor so it is vertical in scene editor but it is ok in runtime but there is no shadows on it at all.

How correctly I should place all the object with the same orientation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your camera is positioned/rotated incorrectly. **Floors should not be rotated**. Rotate your camera/game objects instead.